"Скрыть языки без перевода"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию.
Использую Polylang free версию, т.е. без перевода woocommerce. Как отключить в меню переключатель языков? А то получается, что магазин только на основном языке, а в меню есть выбор второстепенного языка, но ведёт он на страницу 404.
В админке установил флажок на "Скрыть языки без перевода" но ничего не изменилось.
